# Wireless keeps disabling or stays disconnected (Realtek RTL8191SEvB)

Tags: wireless, realtek

I have Realtek RTL8191SEvB wireless card on Ubuntu 10.10:

```
$ lspci -v | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)
```

When I load [its driver](http://218.210.127.131/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2262), according to the Network Manager it *sometimes* blinks with a list of available networks but it keeps disabling itself or it stays disconnected. So, I can't connect to any wi-fi network (which results in frustration).

The driver is loaded:

```
$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
r8192se_pci           509932  0
```

Looks normal:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network               
     description: Wireless interface
     product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
     logical name: wlan0
     version: 10
     serial: 1c:65:9d:60:c7:7a
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl819xSE driverversion=0019.1207.2010 firmware=63 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=802.11bgn
     resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0503fff
```

Configured:

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 

wlan0     802.11bgn  Nickname:"rtl8191SEVA2"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:130 Mb/s   
          Retry:on   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=-100 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Is not blocked:

```
$ rfkill list all

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

However something's happening with it:

```
$ dmesg

[ 6485.948668] InitializeAdapter8190(): ==++==> Turn off RF for RfOffReason(1073741824) ----------
[ 6486.062666] rtl8192_SetWirelessMode(), wireless_mode:10, bEnableHT = 1
[ 6486.062671] InitializeAdapter8192SE(): Set MRC settings on as default!!
[ 6486.062675] HW_VAR_MRC: Turn on 1T1R MRC!
[ 6486.064091] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 6486.248761] rtl8192_SetWirelessMode(), wireless_mode:10, bEnableHT = 1
[ 6486.248771] InitializeAdapter8192SE(): Set MRC settings on as default!!
[ 6486.248776] HW_VAR_MRC: Turn on 1T1R MRC!
[ 6486.580083] GPIOChangeRF  - HW Radio OFF
[ 6486.610085] ============>sync_scan_hurryup out
[ 6486.623814] ================>r8192_wx_set_scan(): hwradio off
[ 6486.830484] =========>r8192_wx_set_essid():hw radio off,or Rf state is eRfOff, return
```

So, does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: I used to have this problem. Seems pretty stable now (11.04), but I still see a lot of logging in dmesg that I don't like pertaining to this card. I think it's also dependent on the router, as I a vast number of disconnect problems with the hotel wifi, and almost no problems at home.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ubuntu Forums they recommend to download the driver from Realtek eg. http://218.210.127.131/search/default.aspx?keyword=rtl8192

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. See the driver link in the question.